# inline div - stretch bottom to parent bottom but keep top inline

Tags: css

I have tried bottom 0, height 100%, reletave / absolute, and I can't seem to get this to work. I'm using bootstrap if there is something built into that. I want to try to do this without flex bc incompatible and also I tried it and couldn't get that to work anyway.

```css
#dockfill {
    /* these aren't working */
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    margins: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>junk</div>
    <h2>hello</h2>
    <div id="dockfill">I want this one to always fill remaining space</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Unless you need to support IE < 10, flexbox should work fine for your layout: https://jsfiddle.net/joc63gec/

Comment: Would you care to respond to the solutions offered?

Comment: @connexo, I was able to solve it without redoing the html or using JQuery. I was going to post my answer to my own question, but I haven't had the time yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code that fixed it.

```
  <div class="container-fluid" style="position: absolute;top: 50px;bottom: 25px;width: 100%;">
    <div class="row content" style="height:100%">
      <!-- LIST OR OBJECT DETAILS AREA -->
      <div class="col-sm-10" style="height:100%;padding-top:5px;">
        Stuff...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to slightly modify the html, you can use a CSS table for this:

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  display: table;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
.container .tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.container .a,
.container .b {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 20px;
}
.container .fill {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="a"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="fill"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> http://codepen.io/connexo/pen/dNbvbg

As a sidenote, ***never*** use ids in CSS selectors. **Always** use classes instead.

Comment: I disagree with your sidenote. IDs are just fine to use - the important thing is understanding CSS 'specificity'

Comment: In 20 years of frontend development I haven't encountered a single situation where it would have made sense to use an `id` selector, yet I had hundreds of cases of people reproducing unnecessarily long selectors, or worse, use `!important` to solve problems based on the usage of id selectors.

Comment: I use IDs all the time to create modular components. It's easy to create complete HTML/CSS packages with a single ID on the parent `section` or `article` and then all of the child rules within that section can use classes or node selectors to apply properties.

Comment: IDs are also really great when you want to create some JS function that works when you click one button. Or if you want to make 1 component show/hide on command. If you're doing some `.class .class:nth-of-type(2n-1) .class :not(selected) node{...}` that's WAY harder to read and interpret than `#someID {...}`

Comment: I was talking about CSS selectors, not Javascript or jQuery selectors.

Comment: I couldn't get the example to make the container 100% height (instead of 200px) so I could resize the browser window and check that the bottom child is indeed following the size of the parent.

Comment: http://codepen.io/connexo/pen/dNbvbg For a percentage based height the table needs a parent context with a defined height (as would any other element with a %-based height).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way, using jQuery:

https://jsfiddle.net/ynhzb2r1/

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var innerElHeight = 0,
        parentHeight = $('#parent').outerHeight(true);
    $('#parent > *:not("#dockfill")').each( function () {
       innerElHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true); 
    });
    console.log(innerElHeight);
    var dockHeight = parentHeight - innerElHeight;
    $('#dockfill').height(dockHeight);
});
```